# Rails trying to convert a string to a datetime, but it's not saving to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use a textfield as a place for users to edit their birthday as a date. With the example, i'm working on, no birthday exists yet. The birthday that i'm trying to add is `03/21/1986`.

Here's the controller method:

```
# PUT /contacts/1/edit
    # actually updates the users data
    def update_user

        @userProfile = User.find(params[:id])
        @userDetails = @userProfile.user_details

        respond_to do |format|

            if @userProfile.update_attributes(params[:user]) 

                format.html {
                    flash[:success] = "Information updated successfully"
                    redirect_to(edit_profile_path)
                }
            else 

                format.html {
                    flash[:error] = resource.errors.full_messages
                    render :edit
                }
            end
        end
    end
```

and here's the model method. You can see i'm calling a validation method on :birthday to convert it to a date. Everything seems to work, but nothing saves to the database and i get no errors.

```
# validate the birthday format
  def birthday_is_date
    p 'BIRTHDAY = '
    p birthday_before_type_cast

    new_birthday = DateTime.strptime(birthday_before_type_cast, "%m/%d/%Y").to_date
    p new_birthday

    unless(Chronic.parse(new_birthday).nil?)
        errors.add(:birthday, "is invalid")
    end

    birthday = new_birthday
  end
```

Here's the printout from my p statements in my model validation method

```
"BIRTHDAY = "
"03/21/1986"
1986-03-21 12:00:00 -0600
```

I've also just noticed that if i do a date of `10/10/1980`, it works just fine, and if i do a date of `21/03/1986`, i get an `invalid date` error.

**EDIT**
Here's some more info that may help:

view:

```
<%= form_for(@userProfile, :url => {:controller => "contacts", :action => "update_user"}, :html => {:class => "form grid_6 edit_profile_form"}, :method => :put ) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.fields_for :user_details do |d| %>
<%= d.label :birthday, raw("Birthday <small>mm/dd/yyyy</small>") %>                         
<%= d.text_field :birthday %>
...
<% end %>
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :login, :home_phone, :cell_phone, :work_phone, :birthday, :home_address, :work_address, :position, :company, :user_details_attributes

  validates_presence_of :email

  has_one :user_details, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_details
end
```

user_details model

```
require 'chronic'

class UserDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validate :birthday_is_date

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :home_phone, :cell_phone, :work_phone, :birthday, :home_address, :work_address, :position, :company
# validate the birthday format
      def birthday_is_date
        p 'BIRTHDAY = '
        p birthday_before_type_cast

        new_birthday = DateTime.strptime(birthday_before_type_cast, "%m/%d/%Y").to_date
        p new_birthday

        unless(Chronic.parse(new_birthday).nil?)
            errors.add(:birthday, "is invalid")
        end

        birthday = new_birthday
      end
end
```

Comment: You're stripping out month-day-year in that order when you do `%m/%d/%Y` so `21/03/1986` would correspond to the 21st month of the year.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what i need to change to fix it?

Comment: @Catfish Does it mean you don't even know the meaning of `"%m/%d/%Y"` ?

Comment: I'm just explaining why `21/03/1986` is giving you an invalid date.

Comment: @oldergod I understand the format, but if i switch it up to `"%d/%m/%Y"` i get an invalid date error.

Comment: If you do `%d/%m/%Y` then your desired input of `03/21/1986` will give an invalid date.  Your main problem is `unless(Chronic.parse(new_birthday).nil?)`.  Basically you're saying that if the parsed date is not nil, then add an error.  That's backwards.

Comment: You're right, but if i change it to `if(Chronic.parse(new_birthday).nil?)`, the page looks like it saves and reloads successfully, but nothing is stored to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a virtual attribute and it seems to be working now.

I added this to my model

```
attr_accessible :birthday_string

def birthday_string
    @birthday_string || birthday.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
  end

  def birthday_string=(value)
    @birthday_string = value
    self.birthday = parse_birthday
  end

  private

  def birthday_is_date
    errors.add(:birthday_string, "is invalid") unless parse_birthday
  end

  def parse_birthday
    Chronic.parse(birthday_string)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def birthday_is_date
    begin
        birthday = DateTime.strptime(birthday_before_type_cast, "%m/%d/%Y").to_date
    rescue
        errors.add(:birthday, "is invalid")
    end
end
```

Comment: Does the same thing. Looks like it saves successfully, but nothing gets saved to db.

Comment: Do you see any `rollback commit`-type messages in the SQL in your Rails logs?  Also, how do you know nothing is being saved to the database?  If you go into the Rails console after your controller finishes the update and get the last updated user and its details, you really see no birthday?

Comment: If you're expecting the result of `update_user` to render a page that has the accurate details, it won't, because you've loaded the `@user_details` instance variable before actually setting the parameters and doing a save, so the view will get the old data.

Comment: I just tried something else. If i use the date '1/5/1980' and do a `p birthday`, it equals `1980-01-05`, but if i look in my db, it is saved as `1980-05-01`. I thought the date format of mysql was `yyyy-mm-dd`? and if it is, where does my problem lie?

Comment: I'm also seeing this query in the logs - `UPDATE user_details SET birthday = '1980-05-01 05:00:00', updated_at = '2012-12-27 06:26:52' WHERE user_details.id = 1` so obviously something is converting the format of birthday.

Comment: That's bizarre.  So if you put "1/2/3333" in the form, do a `puts` of `birthday` and `birthday_before_type_cast` right before `birthday` gets set, then a `puts` of `birthday` after it gets set, and finally go to the Rails console, get the user details and do a puts of `user_details.birthday`, at what stage do you see the switch?

Comment: Also, maybe there's a simple explanation of this, but why when you output a DateTime are you seeing `mm-dd-yyyy`?  I see more like `Weekday, Mth dd, yyyy'.