# Rails 4: Accept year as string and store as date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 4 app, I'd like to accept a year as a string in a text field but store it as a date in the database, in case I ever decide to accept full dates. However, when I try to do this, I keep getting a nil date value. I've verified that the controller is properly passing along the parameters to the model, but at some point before the validation happens, the date has been set to nil.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? And if so, what critical step have I missed? Thanks!

This is the relevant part of the form:

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :publication_date %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :publication_date, :size => 4 %>
</p>
```

And the schema:

```
create_table "books", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.date     "publication_date"
    ...
end
```

And the model validation:

```
validates :publication_date, length: { is: 4 }, numericality: true

before_validation :check_pub_date

def check_pub_date
    # this prints nil
    logger.debug "Publication date: #{self.publication_date}"
end

  before_save :convert_pub_year

def convert_pub_year
    # Never gets here because validation never passes
    logger.debug "Publication year: #{self.publication_date}"
    if self.publication_date
        self.publication_date = DateTime.strptime(self.publication_date, "%Y")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your model is expecting a full date to come through, you are hitting a problem when you are passing only a string from your form - I would create a simple text_field to capture the year and go from there...

In your view

```
<%= text_field_tag :pub_year %>
```

In your controller

```
publication_year = params[:pub_year]
@book.publication_date = DateTime.strptime(publication_year, "%Y")
```

or, of course, factor the parsing of year into a full date into the model.

Edit - expanding on this, it's also possible to create a property in your model that doesn't get saved to the database if you prefer, so in your model, you would have this:

```
attr_accessor :pub_year
```

Then, in your `convert_pub_year`, substitute in pub_year instead of publication_date

```
def convert_pub_year
    if self.pub_year
      self.publication_date = DateTime.strptime(self.pub_year, "%Y")
    end
end
```

You controller would need to allow the pub_year parameter in addition to any others you want - so in the private methods - something like the following:

```
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:title, :pub_year)
end
```

And finally in your view, remove `publication_date' and include`pub_year`:

```
<%= f.label :pub_year %><br>
<%= f.text_field :pub_year %>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I went with your second suggestion and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the very detailed explanation! One further question: I've seen other examples where text fields are used for full dates (for example, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049818/rails-trying-to-convert-a-string-to-a-datetime-but-its-not-saving-to-db)). Is this because Ruby/Rails automatically casts strings formatted a certain way into dates? I assume this is also why numeric strings have no problem being saved as ints in the database.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much right - essentially everything that gets submitted by a form to a server over http is a string. Rails attempts to cast each string to the correct datatype based on your database schema.

Comment: Got it. That explains everything. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists because validation occurs AFTER assignment of the string passed from the controller, i.e. what you are validating is not the string but the attribute after the type cast to a date. If this fails (because - as in your case - the date is incomplete and consists only of a year), the attribute is nil.
For situations like yours you might want to look into the attribute_before_type_cast functions/variables which will give you access to the original date string BEFORE it was type cast into nil.